# Android Adapter getView Method: call super.getView or not?

Tags: android, super, android-adapter

I saw getView implementations that used convertView parameter directly:

```
if(convertView!=null)
    ...
return convertView
```

Another implementations call super.getView:

```
View view = super.getView( position, convertView, parent );
if(view!=null)
    ...
return view
```

My question is, What is the right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about [Adapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). Which adapter are you extending?

Most adapters have no implementation of getView() themselves and expect that you check if convertView is null before inflating a view one yourself.

I say most adapters since there are exceptions. If you sub-class an Adapter from a third party -lib the adapter might actually provide an implementation of getView() and handle the view recycling. In that case you really should call the super-class.

Also, if you take a look at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getView%28int,android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup%29) for [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) it actually has an implementation of getView()

Comment: Thanks. I'm not making real code. It is a general question to learn more about getView and not use a simple copy & paste code without uderstand why.

Comment: Ah, well, if it's a general question then No, you should not call super.getView(). You should check if convertView is null and if it is you should inflate a new view, otherwise reuse the one you have. The most common use of an adapter is probably a BaseAdapter or a ListAdapter and in both of these you shouldn't call super.getView()

Answer (score 2):

the `super.getView( position, convertView, parent )`; is unsefull since the `super` does nothing.

`getView` belongs to the `Adapter` interface.

[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/Adapter.java#Adapter.getView%28int,android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup%29) you can find the code

Comment: Thanks, I changed to the title of the question too.

Comment: calling or not does not make any difference.

Comment: It depends on the adapter doesn't it? If it's one of the standard adapters it doesn't matter since there's no implementation to talk of, but for third party libs or the CursorAdapter there actually is.

Comment: @britzl I never override getView inside CursorAdapter . In fact the Android team provide a different pair of callback (newView/bindView) to manage views. For third part libs I will expect to be documented it it is required

Comment: @blackbelt: true, I mean in general you should never call super.getView(). I merely wanted to point out that it's not a 100% guarantee that it never works that way